# IIS 7.5 Application in Production is MUCH slower than when running in CASSINI (VS 2010)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, cassini

I have an application (MVC3 + EF5) up and running on IIS 7.5 web server in production. It's Windows Server 2008 + SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

Now, most of the time, production app is significantly faster than when i run it in Visual Studio (serving pages, fetching data, etc.).

But not in this particular situation. That is most important part of the app, so it happens pretty often. I will try to explain the situation as good as i can.

I need to "post" a document (invoices, inventories, financial documents, salaries, etc...). That involves parsing some expressions stored in database, compiling them using LINQ Expressions/lambdas, and executing them. Some expressions are trivial, like getting a property from one object, and then setting different one, and some are complicated like running a query against database. There is between 20 - 30 expressions per document position (or line item, i don't know good enough word in English).

Document which i used for testing purposes is pretty big (inventory - 144 document positions, so there is roughly 3500 calculations during the posting). It takes to much time to get it done. This is log from production app, using log4net:

```
PRODUCTION: IIS 7.5 + SERVER 2008 R2 64-bit + SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Enterprise (XEON 3GHz, 4GB)
1 minute 30 seconds alltogether, calculations 1 minute 24 seconds 

DEBUG2013-06-22 XX:XX:XX.XXX – --------------------------------------------
DEBUG2013-06-22 03:59:37.823 – Posting: 4374##M09##1
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:01:01.299 – Financial statements
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:01:02.734 – Stock
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:01:04.981 – SAVE
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:01:05.698 – Stock Leveling
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:01:06.572 – SAVE
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:01:07.196 – --------------------------------------------
```

I have profiled (using SQL Server Profiler) process of posting at the production server, and i see no problem, in fact, none of the request take longer than 50ms. So it tells me that it's not database. Previous experience with production app also suggests that. Inside Stock Leveling, for instance, I call one stored procedure, and profiler says it's done in 23ms, but here it takes almost a second (between Stock Leveling and SAVE).

Now here are the numbers from my development enviroment:

```
DEVELOPMENT (WITH VS DEBUGGER ATTACHED): CASSINI + WINDOWS 7 64-bit + SQL EXPRESS 2008 R2 (i5, 6GB)
54 seconds alltogether, calculations 41 seconds 

DEBUG2013-06-22 XX:XX:XX.XXX – --------------------------------------------
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:46:36.662 – Posting: 4374##M09##1
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:46:37.379 – Compiled!
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:47:18.745 – Financial statements
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:47:20.399 – Stock
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:47:24.923 – SAVE
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:47:26.779 – Stock Leveling
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:47:28.682 – SAVE
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:47:30.492 – --------------------------------------------


DEVELOPMENT (NO VS DEBUGGER ATTACHED): CASSINI + WINDOWS 7 64-bit + SQL EXPRESS 2008 R2 (i5, 6GB)
14 seconds alltogether, calculations 12 seconds 

DEBUG2013-06-22 XX:XX:XX.XXX – --------------------------------------------
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:59:42.003 – Posting: 4374##M09##1
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:59:53.984 – Financial statements
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:59:55.232 – Stock
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:59:55.981 – SAVE
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:59:56.183 – Stock Leveling
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:59:56.464 – SAVE
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:59:56.667 – --------------------------------------------
```

Now, i would be HAPPY with these numbers. Even when debugger is attached, development is faster. Another thing that confirms that database is not the culprit, is when I check the duration of SQL Procedure that production DB chewed up for 23ms, using AnjLab profiler. It's done in 169 ms by SQL Server Express!

I also set up test environment, from scratch up, Windows 7 64-bit + IIS 7.5 which comes with it, and here are numbers for that:

```
TEST ENVIRONMENT: IIS 7.5 + WINDOWS 7 + SQL EXPRESS 2008 R2 (Pentium E5400, 1GB)
1 minute 57 seconds alltogether, calculations 1 minute 24 seconds 

DEBUG2013-06-22 XX:XX:XX.XXX – --------------------------------------------
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:38:41.021 – Posting: 4374##M09##1
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:38:41.458 – Compiled!
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:40:28.867 – Financial statements
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:40:31.503 – Stock
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:40:34.966 – SAVE
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:40:36.292 – Stock Leveling
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:40:38.180 – SAVE
DEBUG2013-06-22 04:40:39.178 – --------------------------------------------
```

So everything points to IIS, but i don't even know where to start. Obviously, it can be done in 14 seconds. Production hardware is able to do better i guess, SQL EXPRESS is only using one core, etc.

Only setting that i changed for IIS is increasing is to increase Idle Time-Out for Application Pool that runs my app from 20 to 60 minutes.

I read somewhere that I sholud enable 32-bit aplications, but when i tried that Crystal Reports crashed my app.

I know that this is very specific, and I will probably resolve this only by trial and error, but any help or direction would be very appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here is a little bit more granularity (one document position only):
From production:

```
DEBUG2013-06-22 07:21:19.157 – item: 48984-------------------------------------------
DEBUG2013-06-22 07:21:19.157 – 0.00 - Quant * StockPrice
DEBUG2013-06-22 07:21:19.157 – statement[GOODS] * Tax / (100.00 + Tax)
DEBUG2013-06-22 07:21:19.157 – statement[GOODS] * Tax / (100.00 + Tax)
DEBUG2013-06-22 07:21:19.157 – statement[GOODS] * GK(1349,P,D) / GK(1340,D,D)
DEBUG2013-06-22 07:21:19.235 – Quant * StockPrice + statement[CalcTax1] + stavka[CalcTax2] + statement[Proffit]
```

From development:

```
DEBUG2013-06-22 06:58:53.810 – item: 48984-------------------------------------------
DEBUG2013-06-22 06:58:53.810 – 0.00 - Quant * StockPrice
DEBUG2013-06-22 06:58:53.810 – statement[GOODS] * Tax / (100.00 + Tax)
DEBUG2013-06-22 06:58:53.810 – statement[GOODS] * Tax / (100.00 + Tax)
DEBUG2013-06-22 06:58:53.810 – statement[GOODS] * GK(1349,P,D) / GK(1340,D,D)
DEBUG2013-06-22 06:58:53.840 – Quant * StockPrice + statement[CalcTax1] + stavka[CalcTax2] + statement[Proffit]
```

GK() is a call to database. It is 3 times slower in production than in development.  Others are just fiddling wiith in-memory objects.

Regards,

Comment: exactly, and it's not that much slower than big shot server. I only set it up for comparison.

Comment: In development, is the sql server on the same machine?  Your problem may be related to networking overhead between the production machine and the production sql server.

Comment: both in development and production, iis and sql server and on the same machine

Comment: which [protocol](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31571/how-does-disabling-a-network-protocol-affect-sql-server-performance) is used? Can you elaborate if the box is CPU and/or memory bound? Can you limit sql to just one core? Can you limit Sql to only use half of all available memory.

Comment: @rene TCP/IP. No Named Pipes. Shared Memory is also enabled. I dont know what you mean by CPU/Memory bound. I can do those limits. I mean i have the power to, but i am not sure i know how. Thanks for taking interest.

Comment: I just started posting action, and I can see that IIS worker process is at 23/24 percent of CPU time during the request. sql server has 1GB footprint and IIS worker proces ~500MB.

Comment: Can you compare query plans between dev and prod? Did you [update statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348(v=sql.105).aspx) on prod? The db and log files are on different disks? and not on the system drive?

Comment: I turned off log for IIS, and it didn't make the slightest difference. I don't think its database itself.

Comment: I turned off log for IIS, and it didn't make the slightest difference. I don't think its database itself. It does it job well, better than sql express. But something happens in iis which i dont understand. Calls to database from dev which take 10-30ms take in production 100-300ms. Ones which take 100ms in dev take almost a second in prod. And it's the same database everywhere. I downloaded it from production and restored it on dev and test environment. Maybe if i switch db to completely new server, what do you think?

Comment: how do I limit sql server to just one core?

Comment: I have limited sql server to one core, but no change whatsoever. Still need 1:30 to do the job against 14s at the development server

Comment: when i deployed to local IIS server (also 7.5 - Windows 7 64-bit) i have 20 seconds, which is ok. I am really baffled. This IIS works ok. It must be SQL then...